# Hypothesis test for treatment with opposite signed effects across subgroups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, wald-test

Imagine a treatment that, if it has an effect, is likely to
affect two groups in opposite directions. As a concrete example, suppose
I am testing the effect of a Republican politician endorsing a policy on
a binary measure of support for that policy. The endorsement is likely to
increase support among Republicans and decrease support among Democrats.

The primary hypothesis I want to test is whether "treatment" (the
endorsement) has any effect (on either group). Let $N$ be the total sample
size and assume half are Republicans. $Y \in \{0, 1\}$ is a binary outcome
with $Y = 1$ indicating support for the policy.

Here are some approaches I'm considering:

1. Test the effect of the endorsement on Republicans and Democrats separately (not a joint test). An estimator of the treatment effect in each group is the difference in means (proportions): $\tau_k = \bar{Y}_{kT} - \bar{Y}_{kC}$, where $T$ and $C$ denote the treatment and control groups, respectively, and $k \in \{Rep, Dem\}$. An estimator for the variance of $\tau_k$ is:
   $$V_k = \frac{s_{kT}^2}{n_{kT}} + \frac{s_{kC}^2}{n_{kC}}$$
   where $n_{kT}$ and $n_{kC}$ are the number of treated and control observations in group $k$. In a large sample, the t-stat will be approximately normal. This approach feels straightforward, but I suspect it has lower power than alternatives if the hypothesis is whether treatment has any effect because it uses only half the data for each test.
2. Do a Wald test where the test statistic is:
   $$\sum_k \frac{\tau_k^2}{V_k}$$
   This should have a chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. Most of the online material I've found on joint hypothesis testing and Wald tests is for linear regression parameters, but is my approach valid? (I think I need to assume the $\tau_k$ are normally distributed, right?)
3. Adopt a Fisher-style sharp null of no effect and use randomization inference to calculate the distribution of a suitable test statistic under this null (draw a 1,000 new treatment assignments with the same number of treatment and control units within each subgroup and re-calculate a test statistic, then compare with the actual statistic). I'm guessing a reasonable test statistic is:
   $$\sum_k \tau_k^2$$
   Or should I weight the subgroup effects by the inverse of the variances as in approach #2?
4. Run a (saturated) linear regression of the outcome on a treatment indicator, a group indicator, and their interaction. Then run an F-test on the treatment terms. This feels similar to approach #2, although pages 95–97 of [Athey & Imbens (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1016/bs.hefe.2016.10.003) suggest they are not identical. It's unclear to me if this is more or less powerful than approach #2.
5. Run a logistic regression because the outcome is binary on a treatment indicator, a group indicator, and their interaction. Then run a likelihood ratio test on the treatment-related coefficients.
6. Do the logistic regression, but calculate average marginal effects effects for each group (Democrats and Republicans) and then run a joint hypothesis test on those following the math in approach #2.

Are all of these valid? Is there any guidance on which might have better
power and when?

Comment: This is called _qualitative interaction_ and there is a test developed for this [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/4027319): See also [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=qualitative+interaction)